# Conversion of workspace to ordinary .tab

Tags: convert, mapinfo, tab, workspace

Does anyone know a way for converting a wokspace (*wor., *.mvs) to an ordinary MapInfo table (.tab)?

I have worked in workspace with a high number of GPS-field registrations. I have made changes (edit shape etc) to the registered entities in the workspace-mode. However, I discovered that these changes are stored in the workspace-mode only - not in the original tabs. Layer control shows a list of the original tabs but when I open the original tabs in a new window, the changes/edit does not appear.

Therefore I would be very happy of there is a way to convert the whole workspace to a new .tab that may be opened in the MapInfo .tab-mode.

Answer (score 2):

No. A workspace can't be compared to a table.
If you have made changes to an objects shape, or data fields, these are stored in the table. You must be making changes on the 'cosmetic layer' or 'layout window' - those items are only stored in a workspace.

Comment: If you made changes to the cosmetic layer, you can save this as a new table and then use this onwards

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only thing you can do is using **MapBasic language**... 

In fact, you could do this :

1. read the .wor like a textfile (open file function)
2. extract the layers order (map from [layer1, layer2, ..., layern])
3. Search the blocks Set Map...Layer 1, n
4. Extract those strings (pen, brush, symbol, text, ...)
5. Apply the strings to the tables which are opened in MapInfo with an update function (you have to test the tablename, of course !)

This job is [very] hard but workable !

If your styles were registred like a **thematic map**, you can use an analisisToTab /thematic2tab tool (.MBX tool) !